# PHP simple chain class methods without create object

Tags: php

in this below class i want to use class like with `static` methods and for use class methods without create new object from parent.

for example:

```
<?php
class Permission
{
    protected $permission = false;
    protected $id = 0;

    public static function __construct()
    {
        return new static;
    }
    public function user( $id )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function check()
    {
        $this->permission = true;
    }
    public function item( $item )
    {
        return $item;
    }
}
$bar = Permission::user(100)->item("HELLO");
print_r($bar);
```

this code not working and have problem. how to resolve this class problem?

Comment: what exactly shows error report ? and do you have any your own clues how to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Well, `user()` does not return an object, so you cannot call any method on its return value. You're also calling it statically, so no `$this` is available. In short: all of this makes no sense whatsoever, it *cannot* work. There are many ways how this *could* be made to work, but all of them will involve creating an instance. Why don't you?

Comment: @deceze use class without create new object from that. like use static method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will not work because user method is not static, try changing this two methods, and this is good way of generating objects

```
public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
public static function user( $id )
{
    return new static($id);
}
```

Comment: @midan888 please see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993405/php-multi-chain-methods-doed-not-work

Answer (score 0):

You can chain methods in 'dynamic' classes by returning $this at the end of method (remember, you have a static).

```
class A {

public function someMethod()
{
  // some code
  return $this
}
public function otherMethod()
{
  // some code
  return $this
}

$a = new A();
$a->someMethod()->otherMethod();
```

}

Comment: can you take an example?

Comment: i want to use this class without create new object from that

Comment: it's simple: if you will not return $this in chained methods you can't chain them, that's all about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you a singleton pattern, like this

```
class Permission
{
    static protected $permission = false;
    static protected $id = 0;

    private static $_instance = null;

    private function __construct () { }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function user( $userId )
    {
        self::$id = $userId;
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public static function check()
    {
        self::$permission = true;
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public static function item( $item )
    {
        return $item;
    }
}
$bar = Permission::getInstance()->user(100)->item("HELLO");
print_r($bar);
```

Comment: @dariusz.g can you give me an example or some more detail about your comment, please?

Comment: the common problem is that sometimes we can build to much classes as singletons even application do not need them as a singletons